# Ajax Request GET query string parameters cannot be configured dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an application using jQuery Mobile, Phonegap.

The function below I get data from remote server as JSON

```
function requestFunc() {
    var el, li, i;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "http://mobil.myservice.org/getpanodata.php",
      data: 'page=2',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(json_results) {
               //something listing etc...
           }
      });
}
```

The function works. But i want to config page parameter dynamically. So i tried to change this code as

```
function requestFunc() {
       var el, li, i;

       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "http://mobil.myservice.org/getpanodata.php",
          data: 'page=' + paramPage,
          //the changes
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(json_results) {
              //something listing etc...
           }
       });
 }
```

but this time function is not working. How can I configure page GET string dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to send the data as

```
function requestFunc() {
   var el, li, i;
   var dataObj = {page : paramPage}; /* change made here */
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "http://mobil.myservice.org/getpanodata.php",
      data: dataObj, /* change made here */
      //the changes
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(json_results) {
          //something listing etc...
       }
   });
}
```

The JQuery ajax() page gives a good example for the same [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#example-3)

Comment: Yeah, the data has to be passed in as an array, not a string. jQuery then converts it to the URL parameters.